# How to get all the values of the selected row of a Grid in Windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a windows form in which I have a grid "gridVerificationQ". This grid contains different columns whose values gets all the bank account information a person have. I want to get all the values of a grid row that is selected, but I am finding a hard time in getting it. I know its a very small thing but still i would appreciate the help provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cell["CellName"].Value
```

Set [DataGridView.MultiSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.multiselect.aspx)=false and [DataGridView.SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode.aspx) = FullRowSelect. This will make it so the user can only select a single row at a time.

Or use for loop

```
foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells)    
{
       if(cell.Value != null) 
       { 
           //your code
       }    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event as:

```
    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
         Message.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
         // you can use loop to iterate through all the cells of the row.
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get values of columns of selected row like :

```
int AccountId= (int)dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;
```